# How do I target the `<span>` for the `<li>` that has `<a>` class `selected` in it?

Tags: jquery

```
<li>
  <a class="selected" href="#">One</a>
  <span class="tab-arrow"></span>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="#">Two</a>
  <span class="tab-arrow"></span>
</li>
```

`span.tab-arrow` is set to `display:none`. I want to add a `display:block` through jQuery only when the `<a>` tag above it has a class of `selected`. How do I target the `<span>` for the `<li>` that has `<a>` class `selected` in it?

Something like this?

`$("a.selected").parent() more code here... css('display', 'block');`

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple:

```
$('.selected').next().show();
```

Based on your provided DOM structure, this should be the fastest solution as JQuery will utilize `getElementsByClassName()`.

A more complex DOM would require a more complex selector but for this scenario, broadest is fastest - and works.

I'm averaging 23,000+ ops/second with the above syntax, and only 13.5k ops/second with `$("li > a.selected + span").show();` as suggested by gilly3

Benchmark: http://jsperf.com/selector-variation

Comment: Using the [Adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) will perform better - It requires only one call to `document.querySelectorAll()`, eliminating the need for the extra call from `.next()`.

Comment: Your benchmark does not having any bearing on my comment as it compares a verbose selector to a simple selector in a simple document.  You need to compare using the same selectors, only substituting `.next()` for `+`.  You need to also test in several browsers, not just Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Why jQuery when CSS can do it:

```
.selected + .tab-arrow { display:block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) (`+`):

```
$("li > a.selected + span").show();
```

But you don't need jQuery, just plain css will work fine:

```
.tab-arrow
{
    display: none;
}
a.selected + .tab-arrow
{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: OP said "I want to add a `display:block`"

Comment: @Alien - I noticed that and assumed it was a typo, else why use a span?  I also reasoned that Steven was brilliant enough to adapt my code to his situation, Ie, use block instead of inline if necessary.

Comment: @Downvoters - Two downvotes?  I must've made a gross mistake... Please tell me the error in my post!

Comment: You make a lot of assumptions, don't you?

Comment: Heads up your complex selector is about 80% slower than it needs to be: http://jsperf.com/selector-variation

Comment: @Alien - Cool stuff!  Interesting to see what happens when you [compare apples to apples](http://jsperf.com/selector-variation/2).  It seems some browsers prefer a verbose selector, and others prefer a simpler selector.

Comment: It's not the syntax they prefer, it's the fallback native javascript function they support. For example, legacy IE does not support `getElementsByClassName()`, so JQuery uses another type of selector to achieve the result, making the benchmarks vary per browser. I assumed you were brilliant enough to adapt my benchmark results to the example provided ;)

Answer (score 0):

or like `$("a.selected").siblings("span").css("display", "block");`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.selected').parent().find('span.tab-arrow').show();
```